# How does R interpret this dataset?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I am currently trying to plot a line graph where on the x-axis I want the "date" and on the y-axis, I want the "percentage_change_next_weeks_price". My issue is that I don't understand how R is receiving my dataset.

I've tried graphing the subset I made and it looks something like this:
[image]

This is the code that I wrote to graph it:

```
ggplot(TechIndustry_Q1, aes(x = date, y = percent_change_price)) + geom_line()
```

This is my dataset:

[image]

There are a few questions I have regarding this dataset:

1. Does R recognize that each stock in TechIndustry_Q1 has the same start date and the end date? There are 48 values for dates but I want to make sure that R knows there are only in fact 12, they are just repeating themselves for each stock.
2. How do I make my line graph look smoother without the occasional vertical line on the graph? Do you guys think it's the repeating dates that are making my graphs look uninterpretable? In that case, what is the solution?

I appreciate your help in advance, I am a beginner at R so if you could explain in simple words I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sawtoothy pattern you see is because you haven't instructed ggplot that there are different groups (of stocks). It tries to plot all the data as a single line sorted by date, and having >2 datapoints per date causes the vertical lines. Let me illustrate with this example.

Here, I make a dummy dataset of 4 stocks at 12 subsequent days with almost random values for the stock.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)

today <- Sys.Date()
df <- data.frame(
  date = rep(seq(today - 11, today, by = "1 day"), 4),
  percent_change_price = as.vector(replicate(4, cumsum(rnorm(12)))),
  stock = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 12)
)
```

When we plot this as you did, you get this sawtooth pattern I mentioned.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(date, percent_change_price)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

If we indicate that there are different lines to be drawn for every stock (by setting the `group` aesthetic), the different stocks resolve themselves and the sawtooth pattern is gone.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(date, percent_change_price)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = stock))
```

[image]

Lastly, this grouping also automatically happens if you use the `colour` aesthetic instead. As a bonus, you get a legend too.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(date, percent_change_price)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = stock))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>